# Where can I find a list of English paronyms?

Tags: puns, list-request

Can anyone point me to a (more or less) complete list of English paronyms (affect/effect, farther/further, alternately/alternatively, interested/interesting, corrupted/corrupt, adopt/adapt, continuous/contiguous...)?

Wikipedia has a list for everything, but [not for paronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronym). Google is not exceptionally helpful, either. After trying out half a dozen different search strings, I have learned quite a lot about French, German, and even Russian paronyms, but close to nothing about English ones.

Any pointers?

Comment: Could you please tell us what a paronym is? :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: there are a few examples in my question, plus a link to the Wikipedia definition. (The [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paronym) would have been way too cryptic, and the [Wiktionary one](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paronym) way too broad.)

Comment: Paronym is a rare term and you should explain such rare terms. Paronyms are similar words from Greek para-   beside, adjacent to and Greek onuma name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searching, I found this [Index of Commonly Confused Words](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/UsageGlossary.htm) over at About.com. It's not perfect, but it's a good start.

Also, as has been mentioned on meta, there are at least two books on the subject: "Who's Whose: A No-Nonsense Guide to Easily Confused Words" by Philip Gooden and "NTC's Super-Mini Dictionary of Easily Confused Words" by Deborah K. Williams. I am not in a position to recommend or dismiss either, but I am listing them for the sake of completeness.

Lastly, as has been pointed out in the other answer, one day we will probably have our very own comprehensive list of [questions tagged "look-alikes"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-alikes) or ["paronyms"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paronyms).

**Edit:** yet another great resource ([courtesy of VonC](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90/what-are-the-most-common-english-usage-mistakes/195#195)) is the online book ["Common Errors in English Usage"](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/errors.html).

Comment: Hmm, is "paronym" actually an official linguistics term?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a partial list by looking under the "look-alike" tag on this site:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-alikes

As the site grows, the list may become more complete.

Comment: also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paronyms

Answer (score 1):

If you google for "similar words in English" you get a lot of websites. 
alphadictionary has a list of 250 similar words.

http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/confused_words_english.html

Answer (score 0):

From the Funk & Wagnalls Standard College Dictionary:

**paronym** *n.* A word having the same root as another; a cognate word.

[< Gk. *paronymon*, orig. neut. of *paronymous* derivative < *para*- beside + *onoma* name] — **paronymic**, **paronymous** *adj.*

**paronomasia** *n.* **1.** Play on words; punning. **2.** A pun.

[< L < Gk. < *para*- beside + *onomasia* naming < *paronomazein* to alter slightly in naming] **paronomasial, paronomastic** or **tical** *adj.* **paronomastically** *adv.*

**pun** *n.* The humorous use of two words having the same or similar sounds but different meanings, or of two different, more or less incongruous meanings of the same word: also called *paronomasia*.

Comment: This defines paronym but that is already dealt with in the question, I can't see a list of paronyms in your answer?

Comment: It also gives a definition of an unrelated word, which might be confusing.