# Any website to look up words with similar pronunciation or spelling?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, resources

Is there any website(s) to look up words with similar pronunciation or spelling?

For example: *stack*, *steak*, *stake*, *stick*.

(It can help me as a non-native English speaker to learn confusing words.)

Comment: I have the same mind with you to better spoken English.

Comment: Compare [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-english-paronyms), looking for a list of paronyms.

Answer (score 4):

Just found [rhymezone.com](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=steak&typeofrhyme=sim&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y).

Answer (score 3):

You're describing homographs, words which are spelled the same way but which mean different things and may be pronounced differently (fore example *moped*,) and homophones, words which sound alike but mean different things and may or may not be spelled the same way (for example *away* and *aweigh*.)

There's no search engine for those that I am aware of or could find in Google. There are, however, many lists of these types of words on the internet, such [this one](http://www.earlham.edu/~peters/writing/homofone.htm).

Comment: His examples are neither homographs nor homophones.

Comment: @Tim what are they, then if not homographs and homophones?

Comment: Homographs are words that are spelled the same, and homophones are words that are pronounced the same. The words "steak" and "stake" are neither. I'd call them _similar words_.

Comment: @Tim "Stake" and "steak" are pronounced the same: they're homophones.

Comment: Sorry, I took the only two words that actually are homophones :) _Stack_, _stake_ and _stick_ are neither.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's a list of 400+ homophones

http://www.singularis.ltd.uk/bifroest/misc/homophones-list.html

(click "explanation page" link for more info)

2. Homonyms with definitions. Also explanation of difference between Homophones, Homographs, Homonyms.

https://www.yourdictionary.com/articles/examples-homonyms

3. Common Homograph Pairs

https://www.yourdictionary.com/articles/examples-homographs-same-spelling

4. Mispronounced Words, even for native speakers (For one, I'm guilty of 'anenome' instead of 'anemone.')

https://www.yourdictionary.com/articles/mispronounced-words

5. Just found this. Homophone Dictionary with definitions

https://www.homophone.com/