# What are words similar in spelling but differing in meaning called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, orthography, linguistics

I frequently encounter "**vs**" words like:

- prodigal vs prodigious
- ingenuous vs ingenious
- affluent vs effluent

These words are very **similar** but not identical in spelling, and have **different meanings**.
(Since the words are not identical there are not  [heteronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_%28linguistics%29))

Is there any term that describes such pairs of words?

Comment: [Paronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-english-paronyms).

Comment: There. Now you know. However, if you use this term you'll be forced to explain it, because nobody except specialists ever use it, and even we rarely bother referring to that class generally.

Answer (score 4):

The only word to describe what you are asking is **paronym**.

Bear in mind 'wisdom' is a paronym of 'wise' which differs by more than just one character unlike the examples in your question.

There isn't one word to describe *exactly* what you have asked but hopefully this answer will suit your needs.

As mentioned by John Lawler in the comments under your question the term is rarely used. In fact it's so rare that the spell-checker software on my Google Chrome web browser doesn't recognise it.

See http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paronym for in-depth details.

Comment: 'Wisdom' and 'wise' are related in meaning. Can "paronyms" be used to refer to words different in their meaning?

Comment: Those would be 'homographs'. see http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homograph however I believe they must have the exact same spelling.